dotnet watch errors on newly created Maui project in VS 2022
I want to try out QuestPDF, and in order to launch the previewer, you have to run dotnet watch from the Developer PowerShell. When I try it, I get a bunch of errors. I also tried it on a fresh newly created Maui project with no added Nuget packages and I'm still getting these errors.
dotnet watch ❌ System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'key')
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindValue(TKey key)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools.LaunchSettingsProfile.ReadDefaultLaunchProfile(LaunchSettingsJson launchSettings, IReporter reporter)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools.LaunchSettingsProfile.ReadLaunchProfile(String projectDirectory, String launchProfileName, IReporter reporter)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Program.RunAsync(CommandLineOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Program.RunAsync(String[] args)
dotnet watch ❌ An unexpected error occurred

I have updated the watch tool, installed dotnet 8 SDK and updated Visual Studio 2022.

I have same issue, it seems to be related to dotnet version 8

I also experienced this error following an upgrade to .NET 8.
tl;dr: I deleted Properties/launchSettings.json from the .NET project, and the problem went away

The clue was the ReadDefaultLaunchProfile call in the stack trace. With previous versions of dotnet watch, we would get the following warning in the logs:

The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied.

But that didn't stop anything from working, so we didn't investigate further at the time.
Knowing that the dotnet watch command has been drastically rewritten in dotnet 8, it would make sense if the new exception had the same cause as the old warning, but is no longer handled gracefully in the .NET 8 version due to the rewrite.
So I found this SE post about that old warning message, and the solution to that question mentioned editing launchSettings.json.
When I looked at the Properties/launchSettings.json file in our project, I found that it hadn’t been modified in 6 years and that everything in there related to IIS and IIS Express. We haven't used either of those in a long time, so rather than trying to edit launchSettings.json to work with dotnet watch, I tried simply deleting launchSettings.json. After that, the problem went away. Note: I also deleted the only other file in the Properties directory, Properties/PublishProfiles/FolderProfile.pubxml, as it was equally obsolete, but that wasn't needed to fix the problem.

I don't know the full details of exactly what causes this error, and I don't know if this fix will work for everyone, but hopefully it will help someone.

EDIT 1: If deleting launchSettings.json isn't an option for you or doesn't work, maybe this SO answer (specifically the .NET 8 section) will help.
